# svnadmin load but keep the revision numbers

Tags: svn

I'm trying to generate a new repository from an svn dump. The svn dump file contains revisions 1-41.

I generate the new repository: `svadmin create software_2.0`
And then load the revision into the repository: `svnadmin load software_2.0 < dump_1_41.dump`

However, when complete, I get the message `committed new rev 1 (loaded from original 41)`

How do I preserve the revision number when loading a dump file into a newly created repository?

Comment: How is the dump of the source repository being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following conditions:

1. The entire source repository is dumped
2. A new destination repository is created and nothing is committed to it
3. The dumpfile from the source repository is loaded in full

Then your revision history (including the numbers) *will* be preserved.

It's likely that your dumpfile doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: When it's being loaded in, it increments 1-41 and then the last message says `committing new rev 1`. I'll go check it again and make sure.

Comment: You're right. Inexplicably, the dump file on disk only contained revision number 41 instead of the 1_41 as specified in the documentation. Thanks for the answer, have some rep.